# Why does the clear not apply in this case?

Tags: html, css

Why the use of clear does not apply here when I am using margin top?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
#t1{float:left;border:#000 thin groove;width:200px;}
#t3{float:left;border:#000 thin groove;width:200px;clear:both;margin-top:-40px;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<p id="t1">This is child 1</p>
    <p id="t3">This is child 3</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be working exactly how you would expect it to...

http://jsfiddle.net/2wuVx/

Perhaps you didn't mean to use a negative margin?

Comment: What problem are you having? Looks fine to all of us.

Comment: Just because you use clear does not mean it will ignore negative margins.  Your margin-top is -40, so that is why it is overlapping.

Answer (score 0):

`clear` means "If a previous element is floating, do not bubble up beside it".

It does not mean "Always render this element below any previous elements".

Without clear, `3` would appear 40 pixels above the point to the right of `1`. With clear, 3 appears 40 pixels above the point below `1`.